# Does the accurate weapon trait stack if I wield 2 accurate weapons?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

If I wield 2 weapons each with accurate (example 2 shotos) does accurate stack? And if so are there any requirements, like attacking with both at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, they don't stack

Per the Two-Weapon Combat rules (EotE pg. 210; AoR pg. 224):

> First, he designates one weapon as the primary weapon. When making the combined check, he will be attacking with this weapon.

And the Accurate quality (EotE pg. 155; AoR pg. 168):

> For each level of this trait, the attacker adds [boost die] to his attack dice pools while using this weapon.

Since you're only attacking with one weapon (the other is activated via 2 Advantage) you only get the benefit of one weapon's qualities.

Comment: that means then even if the secondary weapon is activated teh passive traits of the secondary weapon don't "activate"?

Comment: Most passive qualities of the secondary weapon still apply, but only if the weapon is activated. For example, if you activate the secondary weapon and it does damage, the piercing and vicious qualities still function as normal. Was there a specific quality you were wondering about?

Comment: would that then also mean if I roll enough to activate the 2nd weapon then the accurate of that weapon also activates and an additional blue dice is rolled?  (just want to make sure I get it all right)

Comment: No, because the attack roll has already happened. You don't retroactively add a blue die.